# How do I use this JQuery code to clean input fields of their content onclick of reset button?

Tags: javascript, jquery, forms, button, reset

Code:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(".reset_form").click(function() {
    $(this).closest('form').find("input, textarea").val("");
});
</script>
```

Button:

```
<div class="reset_form">
    <a class="anchor_link">
        <span class="reset_button">
            Reset
        </span>
    </a>
</div>
```

Using the code above I want to be able to clean input fields of their content when a user clicks on reset_form.  However, being new to JS/JQuery I am unsure as to how to accomplish this since I am not using an input button but a div that looks like a button.

**Question**

How can i tweak my code so that when a user clicks on .reset_button that the fields will be cleared?

Comment: Start here: http://learn.jquery.com. You should get to your solution in minutes.

Comment: It should just work, as long as the `.reset_form` is within the `form`.

Comment: Yes your code should works as is, you may just be missing the `$(document).ready()` handler to make sure the code runs after the elements have been loaded in the DOM

Comment: My comment may have been a bit hasty. My initial understanding was that you didn't know how to target `.reset_button` with your selector instead of `.reset_form`. Is that the case? Because as long as the html snippet you posted is in the form, your code should work.

Comment: Turn your reset button into a real reset button? `<button type="reset">Reset</button>` no js needed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
<div class="form-container">
    <form>
        <input type="text" />
        <textarea></textarea>
    </form>
    <div class="clear-form">
        <span class="reset_button">Reset form</span>
    </div>
</div>

$(document).ready(function() {
    $('.clear-form').on('click', function() {
        $(this).closest('.form-container').find('input, textarea').val('');
    });
});
```

[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/ySH5S/)

Answer (score 1):

In order to help you use the DOM traversal selectors like `closest()` and `find()`, it is first necessary to know roughly where your form is in relation to the .reset_form `<div>`, does it have an ID attribute (which makes it very easy to select the form), etc.

However, assuming there is only one form on the page, then this code will work:

[Working jsFiddle example](http://jsfiddle.net/TXT4f/)

```
$(".reset_form").click(function() {
    $('form').find("input, textarea").val("");
});
```

As Jedediah mentions below, the above code will reset/clear all forms on the page.  If you only wish to clear one specific form, then you can specify an ID in your form tag, thus:

```
<form id="justthisform"> ...  </form>
```

You can clear only that form by modifying the active line as follows:

```
$('#justthisform').find("input, textarea").val("");
```

Comment: That will clear any form on the page, if there are multiple forms

Comment: Good point +1 - that is more than I mentioned in my answer. Updated.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to clear all elements in the form (radio reset to defaults, dropdowns, etc) you can use the native reset on the form DOM object but use jquery to find it like this:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(".reset_form").click(function() {
    $(this).closest('form')[0].reset();
});
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

Well one thing to note is that HTML forms natively support resetting via a reset function in the browser:

```
$(".reset_form").click(function() {
  $(this).closest('form')[0].reset();
});
```

But yeah if your function isn't working then it looks like your (fake) button isn't embedded within the form itself.  jQuery's .closest() function will find the form if you do

```
$(this).closest("form")
```

So the only thing you need to fix is finding that form.